# create an array to change color of one item at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a like function that changes color only for a single item, and that item according to its id is liked, however when I like the first item, the id of the same is passed but all the icons are also turning to red, how do I undo that?

my like function is as follows:

```
onButtonPress = async(item) => {
    console.log(item)
    console.log(this.state.buttonColor,'hello')
    if(this.state.buttonColor='white'){
    try {
      const response = await fetch("some url"+item._id);
      const resJson = await response.text();
      this.setState({

        buttonColor:'red',

      }, console.log(resJson),
      console.log(this.state.buttonColor,'hi'));
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  };
```

I have called this function inside a flatlist as an icon, I will share the snippet of the icon below:

```
  <TouchableOpacity
                 onPress= {() => this.onButtonPress(item)}
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon
                  name="heart"
                  size={30}
                  color={this.state.buttonColor}

                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Do, tell me if you require anything else, and let me know how to do it?

Comment: I think every Icon has a unique Id which you are passing as a param of onButtonPress function. so you can add another state for id and check that if Id is matched set the color.

 <Icon
                  name="heart"
                  size={30}
                  color={this.state.item==Id?this.state.buttonColor:''}

                />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need store in state element's id, which have active state (red color).

```
onButtonPress = async(item) => {
    if(!this.state.likedItemIds.includes(item._id)){
       try {
         const response = await fetch("some url"+item._id);
         const resJson = await response.text();
         this.setState(prevState => ({
           likedItemIds: [...prevState.likedItemIds, item._id]
         }))
       }
       catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
       }
    }
};

<TouchableOpacity
 onPress= {() => this.onButtonPress(item)}
  style={{
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 60,
    padding: 10,
  }}>
  <Icon
    name="heart"
    size={30}
    color={state.likedItemIds.includes(item._id) ? "red" : "white"}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare new state name **ItemId**

Assign the item into ItemId state which comes from this.onButtonPress(item) method
Since every icon has unique Id so

Code looks like:

```
             <Icon
                  name="heart"
                  size={30}
                  color={this.stateItemId==IconId?.this.state.buttonColor:'White'}    
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

It will apply to all other because you are not manipulating by ID's.

Try doing that by ID's or index.
Flatlist render func provides you index to do so.